# gesture recognizer for whole UIView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I want to find a way to animate a whole UIView which contains some ui components within it. Here's my code snippet:

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotatePiece:)];
[piece addGestureRecognizer:rotationGesture];
[rotationGesture release];
```

the "piece" is a uiview here which I want to rotate and it works perfectly fine. But when I add some other UI components (like UIbutton) inside it (piece view), gestures are not recognized properly when user touches on those UI components. Essentially, I want the parent to listen to the gestures even when user touches the child object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to addGestureRecognizer to your subviews you add to your view. As in the rotate piece method you might be rotating your original view only,so it will work fine.

Comment: but I use that rotate piece method in a generic fashion, i.e, I get the UIview object from the handler: [gestureRecognizer view]. With your suggestion, I will get the incorrect UIView here.

Comment: ok,if your requirement is just the rotation of your main superview than change the implementation of your rotatepiece method, i.e don't keep it generic using sender, just declare it as -void rotatepiece{}  Or (2) if you require to be generic. check the type of sender object that calls the method and accordingly you can rotate the view

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transparent UIView to cover the whole area and add the gesture recognizer there.

Comment: But that won't help me on the gesture listener to move the original UIView around? I'll have to probably create a reference of my original UIView somewhere